# Pickadate doesn't works with max and min in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, pickadate

So I'm trying to use pickadate.js plugin with angular
I have two inputs, one for "started" date, and one for "finished" date, the problem is I need to prevent problems like, (started date is greater than finished date)

my inputs:

```
                <input id="genWork_periodInitial"
                    name="genWork_periodInitial"
                    ng-model="set.work.model.startedAt"
                    date-format="set.work.model.instance.startedAt"
                    required
                    type="text"
                    pickadate
                    options="{
                        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
                        selectYears: 50,
                        selectMonths: true,
                        max: set.work.model.finishedAt
                    }">
```

Finished date:

```
            <input type="text" id="genWork_periodEnd"
                name="genWork_periodEnd" 
                ng-model="set.work.model.finishedAt"
                date-format="set.work.model.instance.finishedAt"
                class="profile-edit-professional-work-year-end-input"
                required
                pickadate
                options="{
                    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
                    selectYears: 50,
                    selectMonths: true,
                    min: set.work.model.startedAt,
                    max: moment().toDate()
                }">
```

set.work.model.startedAt, and .finishedAt, returns values like this: 01/02/2015

Someone can help about this?

Comment: It's good that you're showing *some* code, but instead you should show us code that reproduces the problem in isolation.  We have no idea what your model looks like, or what data it contains.  Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, `moment().toDate()` is equivalent to `new Date()`.  No need for moment if that's all you need.  Pickadate doesn't use it.